# delete error in vector of vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm confused using a vector of vector of int: after I remove an integer, it is still there!

```
#include "stdafx.h" 

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    //everything works fine with a vector of integer:
    std::vector<int> vi;
    vi.push_back(42);
    std::vector<int>::iterator intIter = std::find(vi.begin(), vi.end(), 42);
    if (intIter != vi.end())
        vi.erase(intIter);
    std::cout << "VI  content: ";
    for (auto l : vi)
        std::cout << l << " ";
    std::cout << "." << std::endl;

    //but not with a vector of vector of integer:
    std::vector< std::vector<int>> vvi; 
    std::vector<int> viTemp;
    viTemp.push_back(42);
    vvi.push_back(viTemp);
    for (auto viIter : vvi) {
        std::vector<int>::iterator intIter = std::find(viIter.begin(), viIter.end(), 42);
        if (intIter != viIter.end())
            viIter.erase(intIter);
    }
    std::cout << "VVI content: ";
    for (auto viIter2 : vvi) {
        for (auto intIter2 : viIter2)
            std::cout << intIter2 << " ";
        std::cout << ";";
    }
    std::cout << "." << std::endl;
}
```

After running, the result shows:

```
VI  content: .
VVI content: 42 ;.
```

so the vector of integers, `vi`, got content removed; however, the vector of vector of integer, `vvi`, still has `42`!

Where is my mistake?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker what's the *extra stuff* ? sounds scary....

Comment: You're the first person to have asked that, even though I've said it hundreds of times! `std::endl` writes a newline to the output stream and flushes the output buffer. That flush is almost always unnecessary, and it becomes a problem when someone transfers that habit to file I/O and discovers that their code runs **very** slowly because they're actively defeating the library's file buffering.

Comment: I should have said "Congratulations! You're the first person to have asked that..." I meant it as a compliment. My sense it that most people just don't bother.

Comment: As a side note, this code is rather verbose considering the function it performs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit mind give a better version? i'm not fluent with c++..

Comment: @PeteBecker thx! i was only kidding..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're declaring the `auto` variable in your loop it creates a `vector<int>` variable, so bascially you're removing the value on a *copy* of the vector

```
 for (auto viIter : vvi) {
```

Instead do this:

```
for (auto &viIter : vvi) {
```

now the auto variable is a reference and you're removing the value on the vector itself instead of on a copy.

Comment: oh, how sillly i am!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Java, Python, or C#, when you store a vector in a vector in C++, you store it by value, i.e., it is copied.

If you want to modify the vector inside the vector, you need to use a & reference:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vectorOfVectors;
vector<int> &referenceToVector = vectorOfvectors.at(index);
referenceTovector.push_back(value);
```

Now, the vector inside the vector is changed.

But be careful about the & reference. Do not store it, make sure that you don't use it after maybe the vector it references does not exist anymore, &c., because it actually is a raw pointer in disguise :)

P.S. .at(index) is the safe way to say [index] because .at() is range checked, while [] is not.